# execute on swift3 error

Tags: swift

I'm doing a log in Swift 3 and I've found an error that is probably silly but I'm stuck and blocked. I need help if you're so kind. I attach the piece of code and also a photo to make everything clearer. Thank you

[image: Screenshot of error]

```
        if let data_block = server_response["data"] as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let session_data = data_block["session"] as? String
            {
                let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                preferences.set(session_data, forKey: "session")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    execute:self.LoginDone()
                }
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `execute:`

Comment: Try set self.LoginDone() on a new line

Comment: can you give me a example about my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift, parenthesis can be omitted only when the closure is the last argument, then:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    self.LoginDone()
})
```

Can be written like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.LoginDone()
}
```

Comment: How do i do it? I'm new, explain hoy and I will

Comment: @amrstack: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.